# Using raw_input() with while-loop and ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

My task is to execute multiple buffers with the list-loop.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1  
arcpy.env.workspace="C:\\salzburg.gdb"  
sbgRivers="sbg_rivers"
buff_name=raw_input("Please insert a file name:")  
for buffer_size in [100,200,300,450]:  
outfile="C:\\salzburg.gdb\\buffer_output"
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(sbgRivers,buff_name+str(buffer_size),buffer_size)  
print "Buffer ready"
```

So the next step is:

If the file name already exists(raw_input), the user is asked to enter a new data set name until a name is found, which doesn´t exist yet.

I thought about a while loop, but I am not sure how to integrate it in the code above

```
while arcpy.Exists(buff_name)==True:      
buff_name=raw_input("Please enter a new data set name")    
else:
for buffer_size in [100,200,300,450]:    
 outfile:....    
 arcPyBuffer_analysis(....)
```

Comment: Like I said in my answer: the way you're posing this question right now is not a GIS question so much as a general programming question. Additionally, is there any reason you're doing this as a stand-alone Python script and not as a geoprocessing script tool? You'd get this kind of validation for free if you made it a script tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
buff_name = "name_to_test_first" # or =raw_input("Please enter a new data set name")
while arcpy.Exists(buff_name + "*"):    # I use a wild card because the new FC include the buffer size, so this is the name you don't want to exist   
    buff_name=raw_input("Please enter a new data set name")  #don"t forget to indent  
#else: this else has nothing to do here
for buffer_size in [100,200,300,450]:    
 #outfile:.... not necessary, but not wrong to use it
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(sbgRivers,buff_name+str(buffer_size),buffer_size)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more a Python logic problem than a GIS problem, I'd recommend asking questions like these on Stack Overflow.

Try this:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1  
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\salzburg.gdb"  
sbgRivers = "sbg_rivers"
buff_name = raw_input("Please insert a file name:")
while arcpy.Exists(buff_name):
    for buffer_size in [100,200,300,450]:  
        outfile="C:\\salzburg.gdb\\buffer_output"
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(sbgRivers,buff_name+str(buffer_size),buffer_size)  
        print "Buffer ready"
    buff_name = raw_input("Please insert a file name:")
```

Comment: you will only enter the loop if the filename exists. I don't think that this is what the OP wants.